# backing up and restore all resources in several resource groups

Tags: azure

Some time ago we had a vendor build a proof of concept in Azure for us.  We don't have time at this point to analyze it, and it is incurring costs even though things are turned off.  Is there a way for us to export and delete everything so that we could at some point easily import it and spin it back up?

We've got 6 resource groups and 76 resource which include app services, app service plans, application isignts, disk, dns zone, function apps, key vault, kubernetes services, load balencer, network interface, network security groups, network watcher, public ip addresses, rout table, service bus namespace, shared dahsboard, sql databases, sql servers, storage accounts, virtual machine, virtual neworks.

Some of those services incur cost even if they are turned off so we want to decommission them entirely, but hopefully easily rebuild if necessary.

Comment: how did they create it? Manually or programatically e.g. ARMs, terraform etc? Is there any data you want to keep e.g. on those disks/dbs there (i dont think so if it is a poc?)? And in fact, have you checked what is actually consuming most and what is the cost range? I assume we are not speaking about 10$ per month ;) one more question, is it all located under subscription with no other services (non-POC related)? how about containers deployment into AKS, did they build some cd/ci over it? same for apps on app services/functionapps. More info would be appreciated.

Comment: @maras2002 - The data isn't very relevant to us.  it's mainly db schema, configuraction, etc.  No ci/cd, but I'm not sure how it was created, if done programmatically or manually.  All I have are a bunch of assets that I can manage in azure, and nothing really beyond that.